# String manipulation in VB (.NET)

Tags: .net, string, vb.net

I'm looking for a way to split a string into separate strings.  The source string is in the format:

```
    Surname, First name (dd-mm-yyyy) (dd-mm-yyyy).doc
```

so an example is...

```
    Smith, John (01-07-2017) (02-07-2027).doc
```

All source strings follow this exact format.

I've been playing with stripping the file extension and counting back 12 characters to get the contents of the second parenthesis.  So I can return (dd-mm-yyyy) into a separate string but really I need to dissect all parts of the source string to their own strings and assign them to their own variables and without the spaces and parenthesis e.g.

```
strSurname variable will hold "Smith"
strFirstname variable will hold "John"
strDateofBirth variable will hold "01-07-2017"
strExpiryDate variable will hold "02-07-2027"
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this approach using string methods:

```
Dim inputPath="    Smith, John (01-07-2017) (02-07-2027).doc"
Dim token = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputPath.Trim())
Dim indexOfComma = token.IndexOf(","c)
Dim surName = token.Remove(indexOfComma).Trim()
Dim secondToken = token.Substring(indexOfComma).Trim(" "c, ","c)
Dim indexOfLeftparanthesis = secondToken.IndexOf("("c)
Dim firstName = secondToken.Remove(indexOfLeftparanthesis).Trim()
Dim dateBlocks = secondToken.Substring(indexOfLeftparanthesis).Trim().Split()
Dim dateofBirth = dateBlocks(0).Trim("("c,")"c)
Dim expiryDate = dateBlocks(1).Trim("("c,")"c)
```

You should check if the `indexOf...` variables are `>= 0` and `dateBlocks.Length = 2`.

Comment: Note you may run into trouble if the surname has a space, e.g. O Doherty

Comment: @VBDidNothingWrong: you're right, maybe that approach was too simple. Edited my answer

Comment: Strings will contain an apostrophe for names like that rather than a space.  Would this still work with an apostrophe?

Comment: @getwiththeprogrammer: try it and report

Comment: This works brilliantly Tim, thanks very much.  I'm going to insert some try catch blocks checking to ensure only those files matching the correct syntax are listed and display an error for those that don't match the syntax. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @getwiththeprogrammer: don't use `Try-Catch` for your normal program work-flow. As mentioned you can check "if the `indexOf`... variables are `>= 0` and `dateBlocks.Length = 2`". If not you can skip/log this.

Comment: Yes you're right, Try/Catch is the wrong thing to use here. The if statements have worked well for ensuring variables can be worked with. Thanks Tim!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow, just accepted the answer now. Thanks again.